# BlackBerry project version number

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me, version, project

I have a BlackBerry Java project in Eclipse. It has version number written down in four different spots:

- in the project properties, under "BlackBerry Project Settings/General"
- in the JAD file, under MIDlet-1 (?)
- in the JAD file, under MIDlet-Version
- in the ALX file, under <version> (?)

And they seem uncorrelated. Changing either of these affects none of the rest. The third one is what the users sees during over-the-air setup and under Options/Advanced.

Questions - why do we need all these? Are there contexts where numbers 1, 2, 4 come up? It's my understanding that the ALX is generated during compilation - where does the version # come from? Is there a way to learn at least one of those programmatically (without signing the app)?

EDIT: #1 comes up in the ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor().getVersion().

Comment: What version of the JDE are you using? In 5.0 I only see the ALX and thats linked to the value in the Blackberry_app_descriptor.xml

Comment: Eclipse 3.4.2, BB JDE plug-in 4.5. But don't you get a JAD file in your project? How can you do over-the-air setup without one?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't completely paying attention. Yeah, my JAD files display the exact same version number that is in the app_descriptor file as well. It updates when I package, or run the app with the simulator.

Comment: I don't have such a file in the whole project. Apparently my JDE is dated...

Comment: Just a bit yeah, but I would expect the ALX file would have still updated it.

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure the App Descriptor is new, because I was previously using Eclipse 3.4 and the 4.7 Plugin and I didn't remember it. It IS nice though, makes a few other options (along with the version number) easily accessible.

Comment: AppDescriptor works for me. It's in the class library, supported by the simulator, and documented.

Comment: Not the class, I meant the file, just got tired of typing out the whole filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should all be managed with the Blackberry_app_descriptor file from the new Blackberry plugin. I Just checked it with JRE 4.5 (in the newest plugin setup) and its all there.

(More info in your comments of course)

To get the information programatically, you need to use ApplicationDescriptor.getVersion()

[Link for the version you are using.](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/ApplicationDescriptor.html#getVersion())

Comment: And the version that comes up is the one from project properties! The one that does not necessarily match the version # in the JAD. Ain't that fun.

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why its not being adjusted when you run. The only thing I could suggest for that is upgrade to the plugin that uses Eclipse 3.5.

You may run into some issues with bringing in a Legacy Project and loosing your Run Configuration (or not having a compatible configuration)